# Long Django process without implementing Celery, Redis, etc

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django view that takes maybe 1.5 min. to run. It is a relatively small part of my site, and I cannot implement Celery, Redis, or any other 3rd party queuing system—this must be done from within my current build. I'd like to do two things (that would complement one another). (1) Ensure the User isn't timed out while the process is running (2) Implement a loading page or waiting page of some sort [if I can do (2), (1) will be fulfilled].

Once begun, the process must finish—this means it cannot be split into smaller processes that check in with the client, because the whole process would cease upon the user closing his/her browser.

As it is now, `view: config` calls a template wherein a user clicks a "Run" button, and upon clicking this button, `view: run` is called. `view: run` is the view that takes about 1.5 min.

I've tried `view: config` redirecting to a JavaScript template page, which itself calls `view: run` using `window.location`, but there's nothing the script could do while `view: run` is running.

Could someone help me out? There's a lot to process here, and I'd like some direction. Something I've considered is hyperthreading. Do I perform `view: run` in a separate thread within the views.py file? Or do I create a web-worker to call `view: run`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered calling `view: run` asynchronously via ajax? Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#run_button').submit(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: run_url,
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // once the 1.5 minute thing is done, do what you need to do here.
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default 'submit' behavior
    }
});
```